# knockout: how to call child binding from custom parent binding?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have custom binding for element within DOM:

```
<div data-bind="customBinding">
     <div class="for-view" data-bind="text: Property"></div>
     <div class="for-edit" data-bind="childBinding"></div>
</div>
```

Is there a way during customBinding call childBinding? It will looke like this:

```
 if <$('.for-edit') element has binding of type childBinding>
     <process childBinding first>       //this part is a problem
 <continue customBinding>
```

My scenario is related to inline editing. customBinding is responsible for setting up inline edit, adding show/hide bindings based on child element class and others. 
The problem I am having is that now I have one custom childBinding that creates wrappers. If childBinding happends after customBinding, then I have problem. I need to call childBinding during customBinding and then stop dedent child bindings.

Comment: The circumstances in which customBinding and childBinding interact is described very vaguely here, we can't guess the actual situation. Please provide the code for each of the custom bindings, your viewmodel and then explain exactly what is the problem.

Comment: It is too complicated to provide it here. I just need to know if there is an option to call child binding. In other words if I have  #elementid, can I somehow force binding on it?

Answer (score 2):

I guess this is possible, in any case with Knockout custom bindings you have total control of when child bindings are called. I'd make `customBinding` to call it's child bindings first always, something like:

```
ko.bindingHandlers['customBinding'] = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        // apply bindings to child first
        ko.applyBindingsToDescendants(bindingContext, element);

        // ... Process Custom binding

        return { 'controlsDescendantBindings': true };
    }
};
```

However why would you have two different bindings for the same thing, this only make things harder. Why not put all the logic in the `customBinding`.

```
ko.bindingHandlers['customBinding'] = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        $(element).find('.for-edit').each(function (i, x) {
            // apply child binding logic
        });

        // ... Process Custom binding
    }
};
```

Hope this helps.